# (Angular custom validation) Input field always has the previous value instead of the updated one

Tags: angular, validation

I have the following directive which is responsible for a custom validation:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[acUniqueName]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: UniqueNameDirective, multi: true}]
})

export class UniqueNameDirective implements Validator {
  @Input('acRole') role: Role;

  validate(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
    console.log(control.value);
    console.log(this.role.name);
    // logic here
  }
}
```

I bind to it in an input field:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="test" id="test" [(ngModel)]="customerRole.name" acUniqueName [acRole]="customerRole">
```

`customerRole` is an object of class `Role`.

The problem is that whenever i type something in the input field `this.role.name` always shows the previous value. So for example if i have a text `Hello` in the input field and i add another letter in `Hello1`, then `control.value` will correctly be assigned to the correct new value `Hello1`, but `this.role.name` will still be assigned to the previous value `Hello`. If i then type in `Hello12`, `this.role.name` will be assigned to `Hello1`.

What might cause the input value to be one step behind all the time?

PS: The original problem is that i wanted to use an array of roles as an input and check whether that array contains a name equal to `control.value`. But that didnt work because the roles inside that array always had the previous name value stored instead of the current one like in this simplified example.

Comment: Why did you choose a directive and not simply a custom validator for this?

Comment: That´s how it was done in guides i checked, the official documentation also has a custom validation in a template-driven form in a directive.

Comment: Ah.. template driven.. I always use reactive so it looked strange to me..

Comment: @M.Dietz Did you find a solution to your problem? I am facing a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is to implement registerOnValidatorChange which accepts the callback to fire.
So you need to do this:

```
registerOnValidatorChange?(fn: () => void): void {
  this._onChange = fn;
}
```

where
`this._onChange`
is
`private _onChange?: () => void;`

then rewrite your
`@Input('acRole') role: Role;`

to

```
  private _role: Role;
  @Input('acRole') 
  get role() {
    return this._role;
  }
  set role(val: Role) {
    this._role = val;

    if (this._onChange) this._onChange();
  }
```