# A validator directive is capturing the old input value instead of the new one

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, directive

I am trying to trigger the validation of my `dateStart` input field whenever a change occurs to it as following :

**mycomponent.component.html**

```
<input name="dateStart" type="text" 
       [(ngModel)]="contract.startDate" 
       (ngModelChange)="onStartDateChange($event)" [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'change'}" 
       #dateStart="ngModel" myDateValidator 
       [dateStart]="contract.startDate" [dateEnd]="contract.endDate" 
       class="datepicker-input datepicker-border"
       style="width:100%" bsDatepicker required>
```

**mycomponent.component.ts**

```
onStartDateChange(event) {
  if(event) {
    this.contract.startDate = event;
  }
}
```

**my-date-validator.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myDateValidator]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: DateValidator, multi: true}]
})
export class DateValidator implements Validator {
  @Input() dateStart: Date;
  @Input() dateEnd: Date;
  constructor() { }

  validate(c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
    if (!c || !(c.value)) {
      return null;
    }
    if (this.dateEnd < this.dateStart) {
      return {myDateValidator: false};
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

It seems however the event handler `onStartDateChange()` is triggered before the validation takes place and that `contract.startDate` is actually updated, the validator directive `dateStart` Input is always capturing the old value and not the new one when the validation process is triggered. A similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60231221/13453311) regarding the same problem exists already.
Any help please will be more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

can you  try (keyPress) event  instead of (ngModelChange)

Comment: Did not work either.